# Disable all controls inside a ModelPoPup extender by hitting the Edit Button asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a model PoPuP with list of disabled controls and i've an edit button on the footer of this modelPoPuP when i clicked to it(edit button) i want to enable all controls(TextBoxes, DropDownList...) reside inside this modelPoPuP. I tried the code shown below :

```
protected void btnEditOfConsultAndUpdatePopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (Control childControl in modelConsultAndUpdate.Controls)
        {
            if (childControl is TextBox)
            {
                ((WebControl)childControl).Enabled = true;
            }
        }

            modelConsultAndUpdate.MessageTitle = "xxxx";
            modelConsultAndUpdate.MatriculeTitle = "xxxx";
            modelConsultAndUpdate.ShowPopUp();
}
```

any ideas please.

Answer (score -1):

Where is the problem? Aren;t you able to find control ?
it seems you should try using Parent Control > Child Control like below:

foreach (Control inputControl in parent.Controls)
            {
                    if (inputControl is DropDownList)
                    {
                        ((DropDownList)(inputControl)).Enabled = status;
                    }
}

Upvote if it helps

Comment: i solved it by using jquery 
`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
               EnableDisableControls();
         });
          function EnableDisableControls() {
               $('#btnEditCertif').click(function (e) {
               $('#body_modelConsultAndUpdate :input').attr("disabled", false);
                 e.preventDefault();
          })
 }
</script>`

Comment: How can you Downvote answer without trying? and even your question was itself not describe what is the actual problem ?

Comment: is not me Shyam sundar singh tomar